# MySQL Current and Past Status

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a DB that houses statuses under one table in one attribute.

## APP STATUS

### ID  |   Status      | TimeStamp

`1  |  WAITING      | 2014-07-10 00:33:14
 1  |  SENT         | 2014-07-10 00:34:14
 1  |  RECEIVED     | 2014-07-10 00:35:14
 1  |  SENT TO CUST | 2014-07-10 00:36:14
 1  |  COMPLETE     | 2014-07-10 00:37:14
 2  |  WAITING      | 2014-07-10 00:33:14
 2  |  SENT         | 2014-07-10 00:34:14
 2  |  RECEIVED     | 2014-07-10 00:35:14
 2  |  WAITING      | 2014-07-10 00:36:14
 2  |  SENT         | 2014-07-10 00:37:14`

I am trying to figure out the count of ID's that went from RECEIVED to SENT TO CUST for a specific time frame, such as today. To explain a bit further, I can get the count of ID's if they were ever in a particular status. But, I am not able to determine the count of how many ID's went from specifically one status to another. i.e. ID's that are currently in SENT TO CUST and the exact past status was RECEIVED.

Comment: And the expected output is?

Comment: edited... sorry let me know if more information is needed. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  This is a relatively simple method that might be close enough.  Get the first "received" and last "sent to cust" in the time frame and compares those:

```
select count(*)
from (select id,
             min(case when status = 'RECEIVED' then timestamp end) as ts_received,
             min(case when status = 'SENT TO CUST' then timestamp end) as ts_senttocust
      from t
      where timestamp between ?? and ??
      group by id
     ) t
where ts_received < ts_senttocust;
```

This tells you went received is before, but not necessarily just before.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (*using `tableName` as the table name*):

```
select count(*)
from tableName main
where
    exists (
      select *
      from tableName temp1
      where temp1.ID = main.ID and
            temp1.Status = 'RECEIVED' and
            ( select temp2.Status
              from tableName
              where temp2.ID = temp1.ID and
                    temp2.TimeStamp < temp1.TimeStamp
              order by temp2.TimeStamp desc
              limit 1) = 'SENT TO CUST'
    )
```

**What's going on:**

Counting the records from `tableName` which have an occurrence of a `RECEIVED` status immediately followed by a `SENT TO CUST` status.

Let me know if I should explain further.